# why does table look like this? - multiplicative table for Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, problem-solving

I have a Group $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]/q$ where $q(x)=x^3+x+1$

In my textbook, there a multiplication table:

[image]

but I dont understand how the last $x+1$ comes. it should be

$(x^2+x+1)*(x^2+x+1) \quad mod \quad (x^3+x+1)$ right? I dont come to $x+1$ however, am I going the wrong way? this is my division:

[image]

Comment: In $Z_2[x]\colon$ $x^3+2x^2 = x^3 = x^3+x+1+(x+1)$.

Comment: As njguliyev notes, your answer is correct and matches the book answer. The thing to keep in mind is that you have to keep reducing until the you have a polynomial of degree *less* than what you're modding by; if you'd gone one more step in the long division you'd have got the book answer.

Comment: @njguliyev, i totally missed that. i need to "modulo" the rest by $2$ since i am in $\mathbb{Z_2}$, right?.

Comment: @anon, how can i go further? can i divide $x^3+2x^2$ by $x^3+x+1$?

Comment: @doniyor, that is exactly what I did in my first comment: $x^3+2x^2 = (x^3+x+1)\cdot 1 +(x+1)$.

Comment: In the first line you subtracted $x(x^3+x+1)$ to get rid of the leading power. In the second you subtracted $x^3+x+1$ but you should subtract $2(x^3+x+1)$ to get rid of the leading power. Every step of the long division algorithm is intended to reduce the degree of the moving remainder. (Of course I am entirely ignoring the fact we can reduce integers mod $2$ within the process.)

Comment: @anon, ok great. now i get it..

Comment: @anon, i wanted to ask you again: $(x+1)(x^2) mod (x^3+x+1)$ is giving $x^2-x-1$. why is in table it is $x^2+x+1$?

Comment: @doniyor Those are the same. Can you think of why? This isn't $\Bbb Z[x]$, instead it's...

Comment: @anon, because $x^2+(-1)x+(-1)1$, right? $-1$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ equals to $1$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @anon, awesome, thanks in tons

Comment: @anon, sorry, but i ask you one more thing. what happens if the degree of polynom is 1? do i get only the numbers of Group?

Comment: @njguliyev, sorry, but i ask you one more thing. what happens if the degree of polynom is 1? do i get only the numbers of Group?

Comment: If you're dividing (modding) by a linear polynomial then the remainders will be constants, i.e. scalars from the base field (or ring).